# Regex to match a negative number in Django URL dispatcher?

Tags: regex, django

I have **absolutely** no idea how Regex works. I'm using this bit of Regex to match arguments for the URL dispatcher:

```
r'^/(?P<c>\d+)/(?P<b>\d+)/(?P<g>\w+)'
```

The issue is that the second value `b` will not match if it's a negative. *How can I change the above regex so it matches negative numbers as well as positive ones for the second value?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
r'^/(?P<c>\d+)/(?P<b>-?\d+)/(?P<g>\w+)'
```

I've added the `-?`, which means: match one or zero `-` characters.