# Django URL regular expression: make URL tolerate int or float values

Tags: python, regex, django, url, numbers

the url format is:
**domain/startValue/endValue/content**

here, startValue and endValue take either int or float numbers..

i tried:
`/(\d+)/(\d+)` which takes int values

and:

`/(\d+\.\d+)/(\d+\.\d+)` which takes float values

but don't know how to put them together which takes both formats of numbers

tried:

```
 /(\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)/(\d+)|(\d+\.\d+)
```

was told by browser that url does not match view function parameters

thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're alway starting with ints, simply make the float part optional using the `?` regex operator, and use a non-capturing group:

```
intorfloat_re = "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```

..and use that string in your url definition.

Answer (score 4):

I Am aware this is already answered and accepted, but looking for the right regex, this one passed my path.
So a little adjustment on the given and accepted answer:

use

```
intorfloat_positiveornegative_re = "(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
```

if you want it to accept both negative or positive integers or floats

By the way, I combined this answer with the answer to this question: [Regex to match a negative number in Django URL dispatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122345/regex-to-match-a-negative-number-in-django-url-dispatcher)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to return too many groups from the regex match. Try this instead:

```
(\d?\.\d+|\d+)
```

This will match 0-1 digits, then a ., then one or more digits. It also gets the float first so you don't get the first digit instead of the float.

Answer (score 1):

this might be old, but just for complicity, something like this might be more helpful and secured

```
"-?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,5})?"
```

and you can specify the range you want